# Enabling Notes and Attachment Access in Communities for Scratch Orgs

Tags: community, metadata-api, attachment, metadata, customer-community

We create a scratch org with community enabled on it. There is a setting on the community (accessible through `Setup >  Communities > Communities Settings`) where we have to manually check the checkbox for *Let customer users access notes and attachments*

[image: Notes and Attachments access]

We want this to be programmatically achieved which means either tracked in a metadata file and pushed to the newly created scratch org or running a script that enables this setting for us.

Does anyone know how we can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `enableCspNotesOnAccConPref` field to enable this setting when configuring your community or scratch definition. See more at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_communitiessettings.htm